# NIFI - How to insert distinct data from the flow and refer to that data ID in other places

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm trying to learn NIFI so this is all new to me, I used to work with Talend and I have hard time translating to NIFI. So the main idea: For example is I have two tables in Postgresql

Table CITY :

ID (auto generated), city_name

Table PERSON :

ID (auto generated), first_name, last_name, city_id

and I have a CSV file :

first_name, last_name, city_name

Can you please explain how I can insert in tow tables from one flowfile and refer in the table PERSON to the ID of the city not the name from the table CITY.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use [LookupRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.15.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.LookupRecord/) to enrich each record with city id and split input in two files: matched/unmatched.

for matched you have to execute simple insert into PERSON table - because city id was found.

for unmatched you have to generate insert/upsert into CITY table and then route all those records to lookup record again.

---

or you could insert everything as is into temp table with structure that matches your CSV.

and then execute 2 simple sql statements:

1. populate missing cities from temp table
2. insert into person from temp table with lookup city id on the level of SQL server